# dict.pop versus dict.get on the default return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out what is the reason for having `None` as the default value for `dict.get` but no default value (without specifying the default value) for `dict.pop`

```
{}.get('my_key')
# output: None
{}.pop('my_key')
# output: KeyError: 'my_key'
```

I was thinking that the reason for not having implicit default value for `dict.pop` is because you may have keys with value `None` so, in order to not get confused if your key is in the dictionary or not, an implicit default value for `dict.pop` doesn't make so much sense. But then again this explanation should be valid also for `dict.get` and isn't:

```
{'my_key': None}.get('my_key')
# output: None
# but doesn't tell you if the key is truly in the dictionary or not
```

Comment: They are quite different in that `pop` removes the value from the dictionary. Otherwise, you are pretty much correct. Throwing errors also helps in debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take on this is to allow a `dict` to be used with different
contexts.

With `dict.get(key)` we always get a value even if the key is not
present in `dict`. The default value can be provided. No exception is raised.
The `dict` is not changed.

With `dict.pop(key)` we get a value only when the `key` is present in
`dict`, otherwise an exception is raised.  We may avoid the exception
by providing a default value.  The `dict` is changed.

To test for the presence of `key` we use `key in dict`.

For `dict.pop`, this gives a similar interface to what `list.pop`,
`set.pop` and `deque.pop` provides.

In short a good example of the ["principle of least
surprise"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)
and the Zen of Python (import this) :)

Answer (score 7):

If your primary concern is if a key exists within the dictionary, it should be done via `'my_key' in my_dict`.  `.get` and `.pop` as you can imagine serves slightly different purposes.  `.get` is strictly retrieval, and `.pop` is retrieval *and* removal.  You will want to use the respective method that best suit your use case, and employ a default value if you don't need to handle a `KeyError`.

As for the reason of why `.pop` doesn't use a default value by default, it is because that the operation expects to also remove a key from the dictionary.  If the operation was completed successfully without raising an error, one might erroneously expect the key to be removed from the dictionary as well.

For `.get`, the method exists specifically as a alternative to provide a default value over the `__getitem__` method, which you usually see the syntax as `my_dict['my_key']`.  The latter of which, will raise a `KeyError` if the key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

`get` exists, in some sense, in two varieties: one raises a `KeyError`, the other doesn't.

```
>>> {}['my_key']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'my_key'
>>> {}.get('my_key')
>>>
```

`pop`, on the other hand, isn't an error-free version of another operation that raises a `KeyError`, so it's used in both situations: raising a `KeyError` by default, but returning a default value if requested.

```
>>> {}.pop('my_key')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'my_key'
>>> {}.pop('my_key', 3)
3
```

Answer (score 3):

The method which read the exact value for key is

```
{}['my_key']
```

The dict.get(key[, default]) is the try get value, if not return "default" version.

```
help(dict.get)

get(...)
    D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example to show you what is basically  going on under the hood,
if the key exists, also showing the difference between both:

```
In [3]: foo = {'my_key': 'value', 'other_key': 'other_val'}                                  

In [4]: foo.get('my_key')                                                                    
Out[4]: 'value'

In [5]: bar = foo.pop('other_key')                                                           

In [6]: bar                                                                                  
Out[6]: 'other_val'

In [7]: foo                                                                                  
Out[7]: {'my_key': 'value'}

In [8]:
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what i believe:

pop() main purpose: value+deletion
get() main purpose: value

if the **'value'** part fails, your program can deal with it, None might even be fine to continue with. Maybe you just wanted to test if a key was there. Using get() is actually named as a solution to check-if-value-is-present-in-dict questions.

if **'deletion'** fails you usually didn't test-delete, but actually wanted to delete and made some e.g. indexing mistake. So if that did not work, you should be informed.

so you might say "this behaviour is the result of the definition, not the explanation", yes and the explanation i think, is, that the same behaviour was present in other programming languages (C) before and it made sense to implement it into python. It might lay even deeper though.

FredrikHedman's response:

> In short a good example of the "principle of least surprise" and the Zen of Python (import this) :)

this also makes sense for me